# JQuery + ajax + json fail to show response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to do something like user click on button, it sends request to json, and i want it shows the response of json, but i have some errors that i can't figure it out how to solve it.

HTML:

```
 <a class="backLink" id="target_button" onclick="insertText('target_', 'AA', 'NN')"><div class="fa fa-external-link"></div>Show</a>
```

JS + ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertText(elemID, text, text2) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://myserver.com/jsons.php?request=getTargets&tar="text"&bar="text2"",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            if (console && console.log) {
                console.log(data);
                var getValue = $("#" + elemID).val() == "" ? data : "";
                $("#" + elemID).val(getValue);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I'm not sure if im doing it in the better way.
It is something simple. User click on button, call the function with that parameters, make a request to json , receive answer and display it on the elemID.
Thanks

EDIT:
changes i made

```
<script>
            console.log('called');
            function insertText(elemID, product, country) {
                "use strict";
                console.log('called2');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://myserver.com/jsons.php?request=Targ&country=" + country + "&product=" + product +".",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
                    }
                })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        if (console && console.log) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                console.log('called3');
            }
            console.log('called4');
        </script>
```

result on console:

```
called
called4
```

it looks like i can't enter on function

Comment: If you check the network tab of the console you can see the request along with it's response and state.

Comment: Doesn't show anything @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: If you see nothing at all then the request is not being sent. Is the `insertText()` function being called at all?

Comment: @62009030 you don't have closing of your anchor and that seems invalid markup as anchor is the parent of div.

Comment: can you help me please?

Comment: the function insertText() should be called, i have no idea why is not

Comment: close the anchor tag and add href="javacript:void(0)"

Comment: @HarshadaChavan the anchor was closed, just forgot to past it here.

Comment: mentioned id is `id="target_button"`  but while u passing it to the function you have used `onclick="insertText('target_', 'AA', 'NN')"`.. Plesase make it as
`onclick="insertText('target_button', 'AA', 'NN')"`

Comment: @Jagadeesh that id , is ID of textBox, it is where I want to show the response from Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I did it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function insertText(elemID, p, c) {
                var server = window.location.hostname;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://" + server + "/jsons.php?request=Target&c=" + c + "&p=" + p +"",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
                    }
                })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        var tmp = data.replace('"',"");
                        var tmp2 = tmp.trim();
                        var getValue = $("#" + elemID).val() == "" ? tmp2 : "";
                        $("#" + elemID).val(getValue);
                    });
            }
        </script>
```

HTML:

```
<a id="t_button"    onclick="insertText('t_d', '<?php $c ?>', '<?php $p ?>');" > show</a>
```

Hope it helps someone another !

Answer (score 0):

Write `console.log('called');` in your `insertText()` function right before the line contains `$.ajax({`

So you can see the function is called on click or not.

If the Console tab of the Developer Tools throws JavaScript errors, this could brake further JavaScript execution too.

Comment: Is JavaScript enabled on your browser?
Is JS and HTML in the same file?
Try to move the console.log('called'); right after the
<script type="text/javascript">

Comment: right after <script type="text/javascript"> it shows on console.

Comment: But if is inside the function, doesn't show anything

Comment: Write "use strict"; in the first line in <script type="text/javascript"> block.
[use strict](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp)

As i see in your code there are some incorrect string assignement. There are missing + signs
`"https://myserver.com/jsons.php?request=getTargets&tar="text"&bar="text2""`
should look like
`"https://myserver.com/jsons.php?request=getTargets&tar="+text+"&bar=+"text2+""`

Comment: `"use strict";` should be the first line in your JS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103945/discussion-between-szenbalu-and-62009030).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your double quotes with single quote.

URL should be

url: 'https://myserver.com/jsons.php?request=getTargets&tar='+ text +'&bar='+ text2

Comment: Can you provide fiddle